# Using ancestry gem to create parent-child-grandchild relationship in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

I have trying to get a hang of ancestry gem for the past two days.I have checked one/two tutorials but they are old and have alot of mistakes or do not work.I have been able to get a hold of a little of ancestry but i want some help on how to properly define parents,children,root and grandchildren.I have read the documentation but i can't get a proper hand of it.The flow of my project is.

----Parent1

------Child1

---------Grandchild1

------Child2

----Parent2

------Child1

Now i have gotten ahold of how to create a parent ID.This is my code.

```
  def index
 @messages = Message.all
 end

 def show
    @page = Message.where(:ancestry => params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @message_id = Message.find(params[:id])
  end

 def create
    @page = Message.new(message_params)
    @page.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
   #@page = Message.new(message_params)

     if @page.save
        flash[:notice] = "The Mesage was created succeffully"
       redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
  end
end
```

This is the index file which displays the data and can also post messsages.

```
<div class="Pages index">
   <h2>Messages</h2>

   <%= link_to("Add new Page",{:action => 'new'}, :class => 'action new') %>

     <table class="listing" summary="Page list">
       <tr class="header">
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Content Title</th>
          <th>Content</th>
          <th>Parent Id</th>
       </tr>

       <% @messages.each do |page| %>
       <tr>
          <td><%= page.id %>
          <td><%= page.content_title %>
          <td class="center"><%= page.content %>
          <td class="center"><%= page.parent_id %>

          <td class="actions">
             <%= link_to("Reply",{:action => 'new',:id => page.id},:class =>'action show') %>
             <%= link_to("Show",{:action => 'show',:id => page.id},:class =>'action show') %>        

          </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
        </table>
        </div> 

        <div class="Pages new">
   <h2> Create Pages</h2>
     <%= form_for(:message, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
     <table summary="Page form fields">

        <tr>
          <th>Content_title</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:content_title) %></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Content</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:content) %></th>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="form-buttons">
          <%= submit_tag("Submit Form") %>
          </div>

          <% end %>
        </div>
```

This is the reply file which when user presses the reply button passes the parent_id

```
<div class="Pages new">
   <h2> Create Pages</h2>
     <%= form_for(:message, :url => {:action => 'create',:parent_id => @message_id}) do |f| %>
     <table summary="Page form fields">
     <tr>
          <th>ParentID</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:id) %></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Content Title</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:content_title) %></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Content</th>
          <td><%= f.text_field(:content) %></th>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="form-buttons">
          <%= submit_tag("Submit Form") %>
          </div>

          <% end %>
        </div>
```

Heres the show file

```
<%= link_to("Back to List",{:action => 'index'}, :class => 'action new') %>

<div class="Pages show">
   <h2> Show Pages</h2>

     <table summary="Pages detail view">
          <th>Parent ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Message Content Title</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Content</th>
        </tr>
        <% @page.each do |page| %>
       <tr>
          <td><%= page.id %>
          <td><%= page.content_title %>
          <td class="center"><%= page.content %>
          <td class="center"><%= page.parent_id %>
         </td>
         </td>
         </td>
         </td>
         </tr>
         <%end%>
         </table>
```

Now this was simple but how do i select the root and child of the node and how to display them accordingly.
I have tried rails console to get an idea but there's another issue.For example
If a parent contains multiple child it displays the result but if a child contains children it doesn't show anything although when a parent child are displayed all its grandchildren also get displayed.I m bit confused by this.Any help is appreciated

Comment: can you show where the `@messages` variable is being declared?

Comment: Forgot to add it.here it is

Comment: I couldn't understand what you're trying to achieve here. You get all Messages and list them. Where in your code you're seeing this parent/child relationship being shown?

Comment: When the reply button is pressed and the create function is called,the parent id is set and when the show button is pressed all the node with that particular parent_id are shown.I don't know how to properly set  the parent/Child relationship.I thought an explanation or an example showing a relationship might help me.

Comment: My model only has the has_ancestry attribute in it..

Comment: And you can't do what you want with the methods provided by the ancestry gem? (like children,descendants, etc)? Do you understand the Tree Data Structure? (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))

Comment: My table contains the ancestry attribute and i can set the parent_id but i dont know know to use children,root,siblings attributes.I can't seem to grasp on how to use them more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

For what I see, I don't think you do understand the Tree Data Structure.

I recommend reading this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)

For you example, you have the following tree:

```
-parent 1
 -child 1.1 (parent -> parent 1)
 -child 1.2 (parent -> parent 1)
 -granddchild 1.2.1 (parent -> child 1.2)
-parent 2
 -child 2.1
```

So in this example parent 1 and 2 are root nodes (they don't have a parent). child 1.1 and 1.2 (are children of parent 1). So if you want to access them you should do:

```
parent1.children
```

grandchild1.2.1 is child of node child1.2 and it's grandchild of node parent1.

To get all of the, from parent1, you should ask for the descendants:

```
parent1.descendants
```

Siblings are nodes with the same parent, for example child 1.2 and child 1.1.

Example of use: You have child1.1, and you want it's siblings (brothers). Instead of doing

```
child1.1.parent.children
```

You would do:

child1.1.siblings

These are just some examples, but in order to fully comprehend the methods available in the ancestry gem, you really should study and understand the Tree Data Structure

Comment: This is good i get that and i know how tree works and everything and i don't know how to see the trees in arils using ancestry like for example if i call messages = Message.where(:ancestry => 20) and then call page = messages.children it should return all the children but it says undefined method.It's not like i don't know how to use tree structures its that i don't know how to set it using ancestry

Comment: `Message.where` will return a collection of Message records. This collection don't have a method `children`. So I think you're confusing rails and not the ancestry gem.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you show me a simple example using ancestry gem so i get the idea..

Comment: I would. But I couldn't understand yet what you're trying to achieve. You want to show all messages (all tree) given a 'parent message'? Or do you want to show only the immediate children of this 'parent message'? What is that you have (You haven't posted the code of your show view)

Comment: I have uploaded the show code.Actually i want to do both these things but if u could show me one i would get the idea..

Comment: I did show you in the answer. consider parent1 being you parent node `parent1 = Message.find(parent_id)`. I showed you there how to get `children` and `descendants` (which are all the children and grandchildren an so on)